# How to check the version of our software from a browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, version-control

We have a legacy software package made for native Windows. I'm writing a system to automate installing updates. One of the options is for the client to visit a web page, and from that web page, check for updates to their installation. There are two ways of identifying the software version: either reading a particular EXE file and looking at its file version, or reading the registry for our software (actually the third way is reading from their SQL Server database but that's obviously out of the question). Either of these methods would work, but I have no idea how to do it from javascript in a browser.

I'm sure there is some security, but I have seen other systems do this, so I'm sure it's possible. In general, the web page can check the client's computer for existence of certain software, and if it exists, check for the version. How can I do this from Javascript?

Comment: only in IE this is possible with some ActiveX help, except if you run a dedicated local server just to serve this functionality

Comment: o0o I like that idea of a dedicated local server, that would work... Assuming there could be like an HTTP server running from a service on that machine, then from javascript make that request to `127.0.0.1` and of course some custom port number. I already have a service on each client machine.

Comment: by using a local dedicated web server, there would be no need for ActiveX. You can have the server do the donkey work(check software versions, read files, process content) and you can output the results using plain html(even javascript may not be even needed)

Comment: Well this web page will be hosted from our own server, but viewed by our clients from within their environment. The idea is that when they're looking at our website, we can put an alert up saying "Your application has a new version available"

Comment: nop nop nop!!! By local dedicated web server I mean the server to actually run on the client's pc. Not the way you describe it. If you want what you describe, then you must go with a global server, and clients accessing it using IE and ActiveX permissions enabled so as to be able to read from the client's file system

Comment: It's both. There will be a web server running our company website, and also a web server running on everyone's machine.

Comment: If that is possible go on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MaVRoSCy's comment above: "only in IE this is possible with some ActiveX help, except if you run a dedicated local server just to serve this functionality". This actually fits perfectly, because each client computer already has a Windows Service running in the background at all times.

A simple HTTP server can be added into this client service listening on a universal non-common port number such as 16580. This HTTP server can handle requests like `/currentversion` which  returns the current application version.

The javascript on the web page (hosted elsewhere but viewed on that client's browser) calls `http://127.0.0.1:16580/currentversion` to obtain the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

> One of the options is for the client to visit a web page, and from that web page, check for updates to their installation

Bad idea and wrong methodology

- Checker|Updater have to be embedded into app
- Checker have to (on start|on demand|whatever)

  - identify build of local app (any usable way)
  - Get && parse external **permanent** URL with data of Latest Existing Build (at least version and URL of Build)
  - Inform, if needed, about new version and|or download|update core, if requested by user|configuration

Comment: This will be there also, I'm giving the users many different options. Actually, this updater will automatically download the files from within a service before the user even initiates the update. The idea is just to put it in front of their face in as many places as possible that they have a new version available (without of course being annoying about it like some software does)